# Errors in Google SDTT for Schema.org Product, Offer, and PriceSpecification

Tags: schema.org, json-ld, google-rich-snippets

I'm new with Schema.org markup, so I've actually come up with the following codes for my real estate markup, and Google testing keep saying I shouldn't use offer for priceSpecification. I'm so lost now.

```json
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org/",
  "@type": "Product",
  "name": "Nodorus - Precinct  17",
  "image": "http://www.setiaalam.com.my/images/products/p17/nodorus-c.jpg",
  "description": "A distinct modern link residence set amidst award-winning green spans, wetland wonders and multiple amenities. Come home to articulately crafted spaces where architecture and nature's beauty infuse home with fresh chic. Rejoice in this cosy new addition to Setia Alam North.",
  "additionalType": "Product",
  "Offer": {
    "@type": "PriceSpecification",
    "priceCurrency": "RM",
    "priceSpecification": {
      "minPrice": "593000",
      "maxPrice": "890000"
    },
    "availability": "http://schema.org/InStock",
    "seller": {
      "@type": "Organization",
      "name": "S P Setia"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add an `Offer` for a `Product`, you have to use the [`offers` property](http://schema.org/offers).

So instead of this (which doesn’t make sense, because `Offer` is not a property):

```json
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org/",
  "@type": "Product",
  "Offer": {}
}
```

You have to use this:

```json
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org/",
  "@type": "Product",
  "offers": {}
}
```

The type of the `offers` value should be [`Offer`](http://schema.org/Offer), not `PriceSpecification`.

The [`PriceSpecification`](http://schema.org/PriceSpecification) can be added to the `Offer` via the [`priceSpecification`](http://schema.org/priceSpecification) property.

So the structure could look like:

```json
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org/",
  "@type": "Product",
  "offers": {
    "@type": "Offer",
    "priceSpecification": {
      "@type": "PriceSpecification"
    }
  }
}
```